# How to minimize $w^{T}Aw$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

$A$ is $n\times n$ matrix. Find a $w$ ( $n$-dimensional unit vector) which minimizes this function. By $w^{T}$, I mean $w$-transpose.

I understand there would be non-linear optimization techniques but is there a linear algebra approach to this?
This function returns a real number.

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: You should add some information about the structure of $A$ (symmetric, SDP, ...)

Comment: apologies, i'm novice here. A is not symmetric, non SDP. Its a general matrix.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** you should be clearer about the parameters of your problem.  So that the solution is non-trivial, I will assume that you're only looking at vectors $w$ such that $\|w\| = 1$.

---

Let $B$ denote the matrix 
$$
B = \frac 12 (A + A^T)
$$
*($B$ is symmetric and is called the "symmetric part" of $A$. If $A$ is symmetric, then we find that $A = B$)*.

We note that $w^TAw = w^TBw$ for all real vectors $w$.  Because $B$ is symmetric, it has $n$ real eigenvalues and an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

The vectors $w$ that minimize $w^TAw$ will be any eigenvectors associated with the lowest eigenvalue of $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Only the symmetric part $S=(A+A^T)/2$ gives a contribution, since $w^T A w=w^T S w$, so the minimizers will be the unit eigenvectors corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue of $S$.